# Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(nx)$ converges uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a decreasing sequence of real numbers such that $a_n → 0$, when $n → ∞$. Prove that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
a_n \cos (nx)$$ converges uniformly on any subinterval $[a, b]$ of $(0, 2π)$.

My little attempt, which is not long, is to use Dirichlet's test. Since my statement fulfills all the hypotheses of said test, and Dirichlet's test assures me that it converges. But how do I ensure that it converges uniformly on any $ (a, b) $ subinterval of $ (0,2 \pi) $. Although, if I'm not wrong, Dirichlet's test can assure me that the series converges uniformly to $ (\delta, \pi) $ with $ 0 <\delta <\pi $. And so $ (\delta, \pi) $ is any subinterval of $ (0,2 \pi) $, but I don't know how to rigorously explain that part. Some help.

Comment: Not all subintervals of $(0,2\pi)$ are of the form $(\delta, \pi)$.

Comment: Yes, but that's the way I can use Dirichlet's test. So i dont know what i do next.

Comment: Note that $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^N {\cos (nx)}  = \frac{{\sin \left( {x\left( {N + \frac{1}{2}} \right)} \right)}}{{2\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)}} + \frac{1}{2}.
$$ Now consider intervals of the form $
\left[ {\delta ,2\pi  - \delta } \right]$ with $\delta>0$ fixed. Can you bound the right-hand side on such an interval?

Comment: Using the classic formulas for the sum of sinus, it can be bounded (fixed $x\in [\delta,2\pi-\delta]$ clearly). After narrowing that down, what do you do with the $ a_n \cos (nx) $ series?

Comment: Mimic the proof of Dirichlet's test. Use the fact that you can bound the cosine sum uniformly on those intervals (the bound will depend only on $\delta$).